# Calculating With GroupBy and Series Problem

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, math, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    ID        OLD  QTD
1   15295       7   1   
2   15295       7   1   
3   15295       7   1   
4   15801       5   1   
5   23369       7   1   
6   23369       7   1   
7   23369       7   1   
8   23369       7   1   
9   38004       6   1   
10  38004       6   1   
11  38004       6   1
```

I am doing an operation on a dataframe and before I was doing this:

```
df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x['QTD'].sum()/5)
```

An it was returning this:

```
ID
15295   0.429
15801   0.200
23369   0.571
38004   0.500
```

But then I noticed I had to change to this:

```
df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x['QTD'].sum()/x['OLD'])
```

And now it returns this:

```
ID    
15295    0    0.429
         1    0.429
         2    0.429
15801    3    0.200
23369    4    0.571
         5    0.571
         6    0.571
         7    0.571
38004    8    0.500
         9    0.500
         10   0.500
```

`OLD` is a series of integer values. I had to change because they differ from ID to ID instead of before it was a fix integer (5).
How can I make the second operation retrive only ID and the float values like before? One line for each ID simply?

I am not sure why this happens but I don't want multiple rows for an ID, I want one row for an ID and the last value from those formed rows. Like this:

```
   ID
    15295   0.429
    15801   0.200
    23369   0.571
    38004   0.500
```

Help much appreciated!!

Comment: Can you add some input sample dtaa and expected ouput?

Comment: Hi! I just included some more information. Hope it is better now.

Comment: super, it is much better. Only missing expected ouput from your data in question.

Comment: I just included that. I want the same output has before pretty much but with the new condition.

Comment: So how is count `0.600` for `15295` in expected ouput?

Comment: I had those number wrong sorry. I applied the edit just now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need aggregate ouput is necessary filter first value of `OLD` for scalar per groups, else if pass `Series` `x['OLD']` to [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) it returned rows for each groups with same size like `Series` `x['OLD']`:

```
df = df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x['QTD'].sum()/x['OLD'].iat[0])
print (df)
ID
15295    0.428571
15801    0.200000
23369    0.571429
38004    0.500000
dtype: float64
```